# Firebase hosting showing "not safe" site warning to my users

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, firebase-hosting, credit-card

I'm building an e-commerce site and hosting it in Firebase. But at the payment page, when user is requested to fill the form with credit card information, Chrome shows up an alert saying my site "is not safe". Is it related to the shared SSL certificate? Anyone know how to overcome this issue?

[image: 1]